# Find k-th character in string

Tags: java, string

Given a decimal number m. Convert it into a binary string and apply n iterations, in each iteration 0 becomes 01, and 1 becomes 10. Find the kth (1-indexing) character in the string after nth iteration.

Example 1:

Input: m = 5, n = 2, k = 5
output: 0
Explanation: Binary represntation of m
is "101", after one iteration binary
reprentation will be "100110", and after
second iteration binary repreentation
will be "100101101001".

Here is my code:

```
class Solution
 {
    char kthCharacter(int m, int n, int k) 
{
   
        String s1=Integer.toBinaryString(m);
    
          String str1="";
         for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                str1="";
            for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
            {
            if(s1.charAt(i)=='0' && s1.charAt(i)!='1')
            {
                str1=str1+"01";
            }
            else
            {
                str1=str1+"10";
            }
          }
            s1=str1;
        }
        
      
       // System.out.println(str1);
         return str1.charAt(k-1);
      
    }
}
```

When I compile I get the output, upon submission of code, I get the error as ava.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Please help to check this.

Comment: Note, that each symbol either `0` or `1` creates `2 ^ n` symbols; so the length of the final string will be `Integer.toBinaryString(m).length * (1 << n)` which can well be *out of memory*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple observations which may help. The first isn't critical but I point it out anyway.

- if the character at `i` is `0` then it can't be `1` so no need to do the second check. So eliminate the condition following `&&`.  This will help to improve performance somewhat by eliminating an unnecessary test. But keep your following else clause to properly append the desired replacement string.

```
     if(s1.charAt(i)=='0' && s1.charAt(i) !='1')
     
     }
```

- And consider that you only want the kth bit which would be index k-1. So once the bit string length exceeds `k`, you only need the first k bits.  So do the following at the end of the loop. This will ensure that you have only `k` bits of information.  The other is extraneous.

```
int z = Math.min(k, str1.length());
s1 = str1.substring(0, z);
```

This will ensure you don't use up any more heap space than necessary.

- Finally, there's no apparent guarantee that the resultant string will have the final length of at least `k`.  So it may be necessary to check its length and take some appropriate action before attempting to access the bit at `k-1`.